# Add List item checked values in grid view below existing rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I want to add my checkedboxList checked values inside grid view(Asp.net), below existing rows how can I do this. This is the code how I tried but that is not correctly adding

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check view state is not null  
    if (ViewState["MailTracking"] != null)
    {
        //get datatable from view state   
        dt = (DataTable)ViewState["MailTracking"];
        DataRow oItem = null;
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                oItem = dt.NewRow();
                string strValue = "";
                for (int k = 0; k < CheckBoxListBranch.Items.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (CheckBoxListBranch.Items[k].Selected)
                    {
                        strValue = CheckBoxListBranch.Items[k].Value;

                        oItem[0] = CheckBoxListBranch.Items[k].Text;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Remove initial blank row  
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
            {
                dt.Rows[0].Delete();
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(oItem);
            ViewState["MailTracking"] = dt;
            GVDisplay.DataSource = dt;
            GVDisplay.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

My `asp:CheckBoxList` ID is: `CheckBoxListBranch` I used `onselectedindexchanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged"` inside `asp:CheckBoxList`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant the below code statement

```
  oItem[0] = CheckBoxListBranch.Items[k].Text;
```

to actually be, notice that it's `oItem[k]` else every time you are adding/re-ading the element to the first column of the row

```
oItem[k] = CheckBoxListBranch.Items[k].Text;
```

Per your comment: in that case you should move the code line `dt.Rows.Add(oItem);` inside your `for` loop as below

```
            for (int k = 0; k < CheckBoxListBranch.Items.Count; k++)
            {
                if (CheckBoxListBranch.Items[k].Selected)
                {
                    strValue = CheckBoxListBranch.Items[k].Value;
                    oItem[0] = CheckBoxListBranch.Items[k].Text;
                    dt.Rows.Add(oItem);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I want to adding and re adding only the first column but row by row

Comment: @ChathurangaEdirisingha, see edit in answer if that helps.